# Receive $.ajax "parsererror" when downloading XLSX file

Tags: jquery, ajax, mime-types

When downloading a .xlsx file, the request is successful but my ajax error callback throws a "parsererror - Invalid xml" message. 
My application requests a file from a server which is a proxy to fetch that file from another server.

On all three machines, I've set the following in .htaccess:

```
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet xlsx
```

The ajax call is structured thus:

```
var attachment = { name="myfile.xlsx", 
                   content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet xlsx",  
                   id="resource_id_on_remote-server"}

var path = '/path_to/attachment_file.php?' + $.param(attachment);

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: document.getElementById('attachment_download_frame').src = path,
  success: function(xhrResponse) {
  },
  error: function(xhrResponse, errmsg, error) {
    //errmsg = "parsererror"
  },
  complete: function() {
    $('#spinner').spin("modal");
  }
});
```

I funnel the call through a hidden Iframe which actuall initates the request.

The server file, attachment_file.php requests the attachment file from a host server with the "attachment" json parameters:

```
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id');
  $contentType = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'content_type');
  $name = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'name');

  $url = REMOTE_BASE_URL . '/api/v1/attachment.json?';
  $url .= http_build_query(array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name, 'content_type' => $contentType));

  $curl = curl_init($url);
  $headers = array(
      'Content-Type: ' . $contentType
  );

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);

  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  $httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

  curl_close($curl);
  if ($response && in_array($httpCode, array(200, 201, 204))) {
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Content-Type: {$contentType}");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$name}");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Pragma: public");
    $fh = @fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fputs($fh, $response);
  } else {

  }
```

Note how "Content-Type" is preserved. I've verified that this is indeed set as: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet xlsx"

The api server which is called is a Rails application and builds the request for the file resource using the parameters passed in:

```
  def fetch_attachment options
    url = REMOTE_URL + '/my_attachments/' + options[:id]
    response = HTTParty.get(url)
    if status? response
      return response.parsed_response
    else
      return false;
    end
    return false;
  end
```

Which is using HTTParty.get for the request. In this moment of facepalm, I will investigate if the content type is lost in the HTTParty request.

Additionally, I am setting the mime type from parameters for specific reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GET request at the end of this post fetches only the file content. It does not fetch the file. So, the file content is sent back probably missing a necessary encoding step with MS files, thus throwing the (at this point, perfectly legitimate) parser error.

This is a shaky solution at best but it looks like the endpoints can agree on the content and mime types to present the file to the end user.

We, unfortunately have no control over the end GET request and can only access file data as a BLOB and trust the encoding of the mime type is correct.